# get current location on blackberry without gps

Tags: blackberry, geolocation

i need to get the current location of device and for that i used the GPS mode in blackberry and i succeeded to get  but the GPS work outdoor under sky not under roof so maybe is there another way or another method to get the location indoor.

i tried with this sample code :

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Location-APIs-Start-to-finish/ta-p/571949

and also same result cant get location indoor its return nothing

wish is there any help and thnx for answer

Answer (score 0):

Read again that link. It explains how to use Geolocation API, which is available starting  from OS 5.0. The locations are obtained based on Cell info (OS 5.0) and also from Wi-Fi access points (OS 6.0).

UPDATE
Read [this tutorial](http://docs.blackberry.com/en/developers/deliverables/34488/Geolocation_overview_1679739_11.jsp) on how to use geolocation.

Comment: my phone is blackberry 9800 and the version of it isv6.0.0.668 and i told gps not work under roof indoor is work outdoor

Comment: `do {goto answer; read answer;if(understood) break;} while(1)`

Comment: if u read  my question it tell get location without gps i ask about another method if it exist if  there network assist  A_GPS or anything else